# Convert Blob from oracle to byte[]

Tags: c#

I try to read blob and sent it like byte[]. This is method that i use.

```
    public byte[] getBlob(long blobId)
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = _connection;
        cmd.CommandText = "select TBlob_file FROM Tblob where blobId= " + blobId;
        object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

I get answer but format of it is not good. My answer is look like:

```
<base64Binary>AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAPAQAAAIFqBgAC/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/ .......
```

Always start with `AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAPAQ` i think that is problem. Maybe i not convert blob in byte[] on right way?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my method for string to byte array conversion (you have to convert `obj` to string first):

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    int numberChars = hex.Length;
    var bytes = new byte[numberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}
```

Also - please read up about sql injection attacks, you can start here: http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/. You have to use parameters instead of just string concatenation.